# Including JavaScript in Phalcon views

Tags: php, javascript, phalcon

Consider following two files:

```
// view/index.phtml
 echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jquery.js"); 
// view/about/about.phtml
 echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/x.js");
```

About will generated like:

```
<script src="javascript/x.js">
<script src="javascript/jquery.js">
```

But `x.js` file is depended on `jquery.js` so it should placed before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have the following structure:

```
app/views/index.phtml
app/views/about/index.phtml
```

You can define the following in the `app/views/index.phtml` at the top

```
<?php echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jQuery.js"); ?>
<?php echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/myother.js"); ?>
```

and then in the `app/views/about/index.phtml`

```
<?php echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/x.js"); ?>
```

That would get the `jQuery.js` and `myother.js` scripts to load before the `x.js` does, since the `x.js` will come in the master view with the

```
<?php echo $this->getContent() ?>
```

Alternatively, you could set this in your master view:

```
<?php echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jQuery.js"); ?>
<?php echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/myother.js"); ?>
<?php if ($is_about) { echo \Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/myother.js"); } ?>
```

and in your About controller

```
$this->view->setVar('is_about', TRUE);
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but it ignored probelm too! We want all js files be placed at the bottom of page. Phalanger should place js files in a queue and render them correctly at bottom of page. Another method it assigning a priority to js files  `<?=\Phalcon\Tag::javascriptInclude("javascript/jQuery.js",0); ?>` Even it can use a js minizer

Comment: Since there is no priority (at the moment) for the loading of the files, they are parsed linearly as the application flows. The solution to your problem which might not be optimal (as you mentioned the priority feature) is to group those files together and have them loaded in an order of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it fits the OP's use case, but for others searching, this pattern is pretty useful:

```
class MyController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->assets->addJs("/path/to/myjs.js");

    [...etc]
```

docs:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/assets.html